# Quelle est la différence entre examen, épreuve et test?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je veux savoir comment on peut différencier ces trois mots et s'il y a une difference d'utilisation. J'ai  déjà cherché dans le dictionnaire mais ça ne m'a pas vraiment aidé...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans un examen, on examine quelque chose ou quelqu'un.

Dans une épreuve, on met à l'épreuve, on éprouve une capacité.

Dans un test, on teste et / ou on expérimente.

Dans le contexte de l'enseignement, un examen est une épreuve formelle qui sanctionne des études (ou une préparation à cette dernière : examen blanc). L'examen peut avoir lieu en fin de cycle (ex: brevet des collèges et baccalauréat en France), ou en fin ou au cours de l'année suivant les systèmes éducatifs et le type d'études.

Un test, une interrogation écrite (interro) ou une évaluation est une épreuve plus routinière qui évalue en cours d'année les connaissances ou les capacités d'un élève ou étudiant dans une matière donnée.

Comment: A noter qu'en Belgique au moins, les examens ont lieu plusieurs fois par année scolaire - autour des vacances de noël en fonction du niveau et en juin pour tous - pas seulement à la fin des études. Les tests ou "interros" ont lieu effectivement en cours d'année à intervalle plus régulier.

Comment: @LaurentS.Oui, réponse modifiée pour en tenir compte.